# iBeacon Notification when the app has been terminated by user (by swiping it up in the task view)

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification, ibeacon

I know there are several threads related this question.
At moment for me the answer is not clear.

If the app has been terminated by user (by swiping it up in the task view) and the iphone enter in a region where there is an ibeacon, the os can send a local notification to the user?

Comment: It shouldn't be able to do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of iOS 7.0.x this is true.  If the user kills the app from the task switcher, it cannot run in the background or receive geofencing/iBeacon region notifications until the user starts it again.

> "If you close an app that has been configured to receive background notifications, it won't receive them until it has been reopened." -- [Apple knowledge base.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht5137)

If you have an Apple developer account, you can read a more explicit statement of this in a [forum answer](https://devforums.apple.com/message/886796#886796) to a similar question by an Apple employee.

There is some speculation that this may change in iOS 7.1.  See [here](http://www.idownloadblog.com/2014/02/11/ios-7-1-fix-geolocation-issue/).

**EDIT:  It is confirmed this has changed in iOS 7.1**

Comment: I really hope they change it in 7.1 This has been a huge turn off and limitation. Currently, I compare it to: "your app can only receive APNS notifications if it's open". That wouldn't make sense either.